# Paired T-test on all elements in two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

I have two matrices that are not independent of each other. The first matrix contains all the data in the sample (pij.unc) while the other is a subsample (pij.expansions). The t-statistic derived for every element in the matrix will be from the following code:

```
(pij.unc - pij.expansions)/se.pij.expansions
```

Some elements in the resulting matrix have missing values (NaN) so I need these elements to be blank. I would like to use the critical values to perform a paired t-test at a significance level of 5%. Since there are 49 elements in the matrix, I assumed the degrees of freedom to be N - 1 = 48.

The last step is to illustrate which elements in the subsample matrix (pij.expansions) are significantly different (p-value less than 0.05) from the pij.unc matrix by using the matrix with the paired t-test results to indicate the corresponding elements.

**Data:**

```
> dput(pij.unc)
structure(c(0.345132743362832, 0.0756302521008403, 0.0233576642335766, 
0.0154109589041096, 0, 0, 0, 0.380530973451327, 0.497478991596639, 
0.233576642335766, 0.11986301369863, 0.0801033591731266, 0.0707547169811321, 
0.0169491525423729, 0.212389380530973, 0.231932773109244, 0.413138686131387, 
0.285958904109589, 0.149870801033592, 0.127358490566038, 0.0338983050847458, 
0.0530973451327434, 0.122689075630252, 0.230656934306569, 0.309931506849315, 
0.284237726098191, 0.169811320754717, 0.101694915254237, 0.00884955752212389, 
0.0554621848739496, 0.0773722627737226, 0.188356164383562, 0.281653746770026, 
0.25, 0.23728813559322, 0, 0.0168067226890756, 0.0175182481751825, 
0.0684931506849315, 0.167958656330749, 0.283018867924528, 0.355932203389831, 
0, 0, 0.00437956204379562, 0.011986301369863, 0.0361757105943152, 
0.0990566037735849, 0.254237288135593), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", 
    "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")))
> dput(pij.expansions)
structure(c(0.347826086956522, 0.06841046277666, 0.0223367697594502, 
0.00416666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.380434782608696, 0.496981891348089, 
0.214776632302405, 0.102083333333333, 0.0423452768729642, 0.0416666666666667, 
0, 0.195652173913043, 0.235412474849095, 0.422680412371134, 0.297916666666667, 
0.143322475570033, 0.0892857142857143, 0.0227272727272727, 0.0652173913043478, 
0.122736418511066, 0.238831615120275, 0.310416666666667, 0.293159609120521, 
0.196428571428571, 0.113636363636364, 0.0108695652173913, 0.0583501006036217, 
0.0790378006872852, 0.197916666666667, 0.306188925081433, 0.25, 
0.227272727272727, 0, 0.0181086519114688, 0.0171821305841924, 
0.0770833333333333, 0.179153094462541, 0.31547619047619, 0.386363636363636, 
0, 0, 0.00515463917525773, 0.0104166666666667, 0.0358306188925081, 
0.107142857142857, 0.25), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
    i = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", 
    "Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")))
> dput(se.pij.expansions)
structure(c(0.0496556731061009, 0.0113238829323994, 0.00612552522134995, 
0.00294013376805785, 0, 0, 0, 0.050616219989052, 0.0224276566035036, 
0.0170227072179964, 0.0138189427951943, 0.0114931156846934, 0.0154169347896032, 
0, 0.0413590325495694, 0.0190304976845528, 0.0204763580615662, 
0.0208747418341765, 0.0199984644008619, 0.0220002401921688, 0.0224675239369128, 
0.0257420488306169, 0.0147188398197043, 0.0176735904252973, 0.0211176347970434, 
0.0259802639138251, 0.0306520786752498, 0.0478451908136753, 0.0108103300885613, 
0.0105144689389788, 0.0111834766085794, 0.0181857120955242, 0.0263054760303272, 
0.033407655239053, 0.0631772101298374, 0, 0.0059813137318308, 
0.00538658524860749, 0.0121742122482623, 0.0218863858749651, 
0.0358527879402456, 0.0734052848078121, 0, 0, 0.00296835221921245, 
0.00463414854688859, 0.0106080274505592, 0.0238626108850379, 
0.0652791209833867), .Dim = c(7L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(i = c("Aaa", 
"Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa"), j = c("Aaa", "Aa", "A", 
"Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")))
```

**Expected Output:**
This is how I would like the matrix to look like. I would like to replace the significant values with an asterisks instead of using the bold font.

[image]

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the expected output.

Comment: The degrees of freedom is based on the size of the samples, not the number of comparisons.

Comment: I understand your point. The papers I'm citing only consider the number of states (N) when considering the degrees of freedom. Typically it's (N-1)^2.